# Ошибка при проверке if

Tags: javascript

Я проверяю есть ли кнопка , и удаляю элементы . И мне вылезает ошибка `Uncaught ReferenceError: buttonTemp is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>`. Условие прошло , и не нашлом кнопки , но почему ошибка? Объясните новичку пожалуйста !

```js
if (document.getElementById('buttonTemp')) {
  buttonTemp.remove()
  buttonPrecip.remove()
  buttonWind.remove()
}
```

Comment: Само условие срабатывает , но в консоли ошибка , что делать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к `buttonTemp` где-то еще.

```js
if (buttonTemp = document.getElementById('buttonTemp')){
  buttonTemp.remove()
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам , вы мне помогли !

Comment: @АртемПашков Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.